# Сравнивание элементов списка python

Tags: python

```
Coordinates_list = ["a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "a", "d"]
IDs_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

Duplicates_ID = []
for i in range(len(Coordinates_list)):
  for j in range(i + 1, len(Coordinates_list)):  
    if j < len(Coordinates_list) and Coordinates_list[i] == Coordinates_list[j]: Duplicates_ID.append(IDs_list[j])
    else: pass
print(Duplicates_ID)
```

Почему результат: [1, 5, 5, 4]? Хотя должен быть: [1, 4, 5]

Сам разобрался в итоге благодаря ответу @Xander, просто применяем команду set и превращаем в список:

```
Coordinates_list = ["a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "a", "d"]
IDs_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

Duplicates_ID = list()
for i in range(len(Coordinates_list)):
  for j in range(i + 1, len(Coordinates_list)):  
    if j < len(Coordinates_list) and Coordinates_list[i] == Coordinates_list[j]: Duplicates_ID.append(IDs_list[j])
    else: pass; print("pass")
Duplicates_ID = list(set(Duplicates_ID))
print(Duplicates_ID)
```

Comment: Да нет. Именно такой результат работы Вашей программы и должен быть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому, что у вас по разу сравнивается каждый элемент с каждым предыдущим, и при совпадении позиция элемента заносится в список с результатами.

Соответственно, у вас `a` в позиции `5` сравнивается и с `a` в позиции `0`, и с `a` в позиции `1`. И на оба совпадения позиция `5` добавляется в результат.